# scale issues when adding images to a video

Tags: ffmpeg

When I add two images to a video, the second image added is scaled down for some reason.

I have two images arrow.png and icon1.png and one background.mp4 video, when I added the two images onto the video, the result is that the first image is added with the right size, but the second image is added with reduced size, probably in half of the specified size.

this is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i background.mp4 -i arrow.png -i icon1.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=311:175,setsar=1,format=bgra[img1];
[img1]rotate=30*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(30*PI/180):oh=roth(30*PI/180)[rotate1];[2:v]scale=319:179,setsar=1,format=bgra[img2];
[img2]rotate=59*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(59*PI/180):oh=roth(59*PI/180)[rotate2];[0][rotate1]overlay=242:-22:enable='between(t,0,6)',scale=hd720[overlay1];
[overlay1][rotate2]overlay=34:13:enable='between(t,0,6)',scale=hd720" -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -y test01.mp4
```

I am expecting the same size as the specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the scale after the first overlay is unintended. Remove it and check.

`ffmpeg -i background.mp4 -i arrow.png -i icon1.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=311:175,setsar=1,format=bgra[img1];
[img1]rotate=30*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(30*PI/180):oh=roth(30*PI/180)[rotate1];[2:v]scale=319:179,setsar=1,format=bgra[img2];
[img2]rotate=59*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(59*PI/180):oh=roth(59*PI/180)[rotate2];[0][rotate1]overlay=242:-22:enable='between(t,0,6)'[overlay1];
[overlay1][rotate2]overlay=34:13:enable='between(t,0,6)',scale=hd720" -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -y test01.mp4`